# In Sql what can I use similar to Inner Join, but with different columns in ON?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I need to use sql code similar to Inner Join, but with the ability to use different columns in ON. Maybe there is something more pointed and specific that I can use. What do you think I would need? How can I fix?

What I want to do, in order, is:

1. Observe the next Chicago hockey matchs (Chicago-Minnesota) in the `NEXT` table. Chicago is featured in `ClubHome`

**NEXT**

| ClubHome | ClubAway | Tournament |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chicago | Minnesota | NHL |
| New York | Los Angeles | NHL |
| Dallas | Vegas Gold | NHL |

2. In the Results table, if Chicago is in `ClubHome` then I extract `ScoreHome` for each Chicago `(1, 1)`. If Chicago is in `ClubAway` then I extract `ScoreAway` for each Chicago `(4,1)`. Next i want to count Chicago's points total and would like to get `1, 4, 1, 1`.
3. Naturally, I'd like to get the same thing for the other teams in the ClubHome column in Next, so **New York**, **Dallas** and others that I haven't included in the example.
   For **Chicago** I would like to recover `1, 4, 1, 1`,
   for **New York** I would like to recover `2, 3, 2`,
   for **Dallas** I would like to recover `0, 3, 1`,
   and other clubs in the column that I didn't enter in the example

**RESULTS**

| ClubHome | ClubAway | Tournament | Round | ScoreHome | ScoreAway |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CHICAGO | Toronto | NHL | 8 | 1 | 2 |
| New York | Vegas | NHL | 8 | 2 | 3 |
| Dallas | CHICAGO | NHL | 7 | 0 | 4 |
| Ottawa | New York | NHL | 7 | 3 | 3 |
| CHICAGO | Buffalo Sab | NHL | 6 | 1 | 0 |
| Vegas | CHICAGO | NHL | 6 | 4 | 1 |
| New York | Dallas | NHL | 5 | 2 | 3 |
| Dallas | Buffalo Sab | NHL | 5 | 1 | 2 |

4. I thought (but I could be wrong) that I need something like Inner Join, because Chicago from the ClubHome column in the Next table...must match **BOTH** ClubHome and ClubAway from the Results table. Maybe I'm wrong. I need the loop `for x in my.fetchall()` necessarily because I've already started writing the project this way using the loop

**OUTPUT**

I would like to get these outputs:

```
Chicago-Minnesota, (1, 4, 1, 1)
New York-Los Angeles,(2, 3, 2) 
Dallas-Vegas Gold, (0, 3, 1)
...and other clubs
```

```
my = cursor.execute('''SELECT Next.ClubHhome||"-"||Next.ClubAway,
                              Results.ScoreHome, Results.ScoreAway
                       FROM Next
                       INNER JOIN Results 
                       ON
                       Next.ClubHhome = Results.ClubHhome OR Results.ClubAway
                       ''') 

for x in my.fetchall():
    print(x)
```

P.S: I use Sqlite

Comment: Can you provide your expected output, please?

Comment: Let me see if I understand. For each ClubHome in the Next table (Chicago, Arizona, Dallas) you want to display their total score from the Results table? (7, null, 0)?

Comment: It's still a little unclear. Do you want one row like `Chicago-Minnesota, (1, 2, 4, 1)` or do you want 4 rows like `Chicago-Minnesota 1`, `Chicago-Minnesota 2`, `Chicago-Minnesota 4`, `Chicago-Minnesota 1`? Are you sure it's `Chicago-Minnesota` and not just `Chicago`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It remains unclear exactly what you want, but I'm going to answer for when you want all the scores from each team in next.clubhome, one row per score.

---

Select from next, and join on results. Join on either results.clubhome OR results.clubaway. You've *almost* got it. `Next.ClubHome = Results.ClubHome OR Results.ClubAway` means `(Next.ClubHome = Results.ClubHome) OR Results.ClubAway` so that's going to be true anytime `Results.ClubAway` is true. What you want is `Next.ClubHome = Results.ClubHome OR Next.ClubHome = Results.ClubAway`, or `Next.ClubHome in (Results.ClubHome, Results.ClubAway)`.

If you want to include all teams in next even if they have no rows in results, use a left join.

Then use a case statement to decide which score column to use. Check if next.clubhome matches results.clubhome or clubaway.

```
select
  n.clubhome,
  case
  when n.clubhome = r.clubhome then r.scorehome
  when n.clubhome = r.clubaway then r.scoreaway
  end as score
from next n
left join results r on n.clubhome in (r.clubhome, r.clubaway)
```

If you want one row per team, group by next.clubhome and use `group_concat` to concatenate all the scores into a single list per team.

```
select
  n.clubhome,
  group_concat(
    case
    when n.clubhome = r.clubhome then r.scorehome
    when n.clubhome = r.clubaway then r.scoreaway
    end
  ) as score
from next n
left join results r on n.clubhome in (r.clubhome, r.clubaway)
group by n.clubhome
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/DcQ_ZQej).

Comment: My Chicago is just one example. I would like to pull data for each game of the NEXT table. So I would like to fetch the data of Chicago, Arizona, Dallas and so many others from the same NEXT table. You specifically wrote Chicago in your code, but I don't need that. I need to recover data from multiple games as you can see from the loop. Can you change your code please? Thank you

Comment: @Takao Please edit your question to fully describe your expected results. Make a table like you did for the data. Most SQL problems can be solved without loops.

Comment: Ok wait a few minutes I'll edit. Thank you

Comment: I need to retrieve the list of results, not the total score. In step 3 of my question, there are examples of what I want to achieve

Comment: @Takao I think I get it now, but it would be easier to understand if you provided 1) complete sample data and 2) the exact result you want from that data, preferably formatted as a table. Then there will be no misunderstanding.

Comment: I'm glad you understand now. I've edited my question again by adding the exact result I want from that data (output below). I don't know what else to provide regarding the sample data. The sample data entered is very clear. I hope you can help me. Thank you

Comment: After editing my question, I realized I misspelled the Chicago output. I have now corrected. Chicago's output is 1, 4, 1, 1. Excuse me, please excuse me

Comment: I'm testing. Give me some minutes. Thank you